# Android animate view into popupwindow

Tags: android, animation, popup

I'm trying to make an animation for a widget, when you click on it, it should do a scale animation. When the animation ends, a popup window appears and the scaled image view is captured in the popup window. The popup window will contain some other views to the right of this view.
When it's clicked outside, the popup window will disappear and the image will scale back to position.

I tried using a popup window animation but does not look good. And I have problems withe the window. I can't get it to wrap content.

```
PopupWindow popupMenu = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```

This does not make it wrap content and it disables my close when it's clicked outside.
Does anyone have a better approach?

[image: Android folder]

This is an example of how folders work on android, you click on the widget and the views animate into their place, I want my view to scale into it's place.

Comment: I have not used `PopupWindow`. To help you get answers, I suggest that you explain more completely what "does not look good' means and what "does not make it wrap content" means. For the latter, you might consider using screenshots. If you cannot upload screenshots directly to Stack Overflow, upload them elsewhere and link to them from your question.